# Error training images using tensorflow inception v3

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-recognition, tensorflow

I am implementing image classification using TensorFlow Inception v3 with GTX 1060 GPU. I trained around 3000 images in 9 different classifier, where each classifier contains from 100 to 500 images(100*100 px) using  tensor for poets.
But when I have images more than 500, it throws out error and training fails. Same class with less images trains without error. My Image data size for each class is around 5000~10000 but only I can train data size of around 300~400. more of the data and it gives out following GPU error.

[image]

The specification as follows:

- Windows 7 with GeForce GTX 1060
- Anaconda 3 with python 3.5
- Tensorflow Inception V3

Answer (score 0):

I am novice for Tensorflow but I had faced the same problem.
My suggestion would be:

Try to rename all the images like:

TrainImage001.jpg

TrainImage002.jpg

TrainImage003.jpg

and try converting your images to jpg.

Still I am not sure but at least give it a try.. :)